# @Autowired not working with custom AccessDecisionVoter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I am implementing a custom AccessDecisionVoter and I have a JPA repository which I need to autowire in the custom AccessDecisionVoter implementation. @Autowire is simply not working for neither a Service or Jpa Repository inside this class.

[image: Project Structure]
Project Structure

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

DynamicAuthorizationVoter.java

```
@Component
public class DynamicAuthorizationVoter implements AccessDecisionVoter<FilterInvocation> {
    @Autowired
    private PrivilegeRepository privilegeRepo;

    @Override
    public boolean supports(ConfigAttribute attribute) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int vote(Authentication authentication, FilterInvocation object, Collection<ConfigAttribute> collection) {
        String url = determineModule(object);
        if (authentication == null || authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) {
            return ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
        }

        return isAccessGranted(authentication, object.getRequestUrl())? ACCESS_GRANTED : ACCESS_DENIED;
    }

    String determineModule(FilterInvocation filterObject){
        String url = filterObject.getRequestUrl();
        return url;
    }

    boolean isAccessGranted(Authentication authObject, String url){

        Set<Privilege> privileges = privilegeRepo.findByUrl(url);

        String userRole;
        for(GrantedAuthority authority : authObject.getAuthorities()){
            userRole = authority.getAuthority();
            for(Privilege priv : privileges){
                if(priv.equals(userRole)){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

PrivilegeRepository.java

```
public interface PrivilegeRepository extends JpaRepository<Privilege, Long> {
    Set<Privilege> findByName(String name);
    Set<Privilege> findByUrl(String url);
}
```

For @Autowire to work inside the DynamicAuthorizationVoter class, I changed the @Component to @Service, @Configuration and everything else I found here on SO but none of them works. This JPA Repository is @Autowired everywhere else.

I will appreciate all the help.

-Adil

Comment: Spring Data Jpa don't required for implementation of this interface unless there is something specific that needs to be done.

Comment: Could you provide more information about the error you receive during the  application deploy? Regards,

Comment: I don't see any error during deployment except that when the DynamicAuthorizationVoter.voter method is hit, privilegeRepo is null which means that it hasn't been autowired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, if you don't see any error during deployment, `autowired` worked fine because it is required by default. See the [@Autowired documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html#required--)

Anyway, try to use an `@Autowired` constructor instead of an `@Autowired` property.

```
private PrivilegeRepository privilegeRepo;

@Autowired
public DynamicAuthorizationVoter(PrivilegeRepository privilegeRepo){
  this.privilegeRepo = privilegeRepo;
}
```

With that, you could add a **breakpoint to this constructor and debug it** to know if the `autowire` process works well.

Also, remember that to use the `DynamicAuthorizationVoter` instance you **mustn't** declare it as `new`. You must include the following code in the related class where you want to use it.

```
@Autowired
AccessDecisionVoter dynamicAuthorizationVoter;
```

Hope it helps,